# Comparing two count results using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I really need help for my database exam.
I have a movie database and I have to list every actor who has done more movies than Vincent Cassel. 
My schemas are

```
CREATE TABLE "ACTOR" 
   (    
    "codactor" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "name" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "surname" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "country" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
CREATE TABLE "FILM" 
   (    
    "CODFILM" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "title" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "GENERE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "duration" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "year" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "earnings" FLOAT(63), 
    "valutation" NUMBER(2,1)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
CREATE TABLE "Plays" 
   (    
    "CODFILM" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "codactor" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "role" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
    "income" FLOAT(63)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
```

Considering this, I don't know how to count how many movies Vincent Cassel did and than comparing the result with the count of movies done by every actor and selecting only the actors who have done more movies than Vincent Cassel.
Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: I've removed all those different dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Looks like Oracle Syntx

Comment: It's not good practice to force column names to a nonstandard case. Now you have `ACTOR."codactor"` (column name forced to lowercase) but "FILM.CODFILM" (case-insensitive), and `"Plays".CODFILM` (table name forced to mixed case, column name case-insensitive). It's going to be a real pain to work with.

Comment: Are you actually sitting in the exam right now?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my first post, it won't happen again.
No, I'm not at the exam right now, the exam is in four days, and currently I'm trying to solve all the unsolved questions.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you number of movies, in which Vincent Cassell starred:

```
select A.codactor, COUNT(P.codfilm) HowManyMovies
from Plays P join Actor A
on P.codactor = A.codactor
where A.name = 'Vincent Cassel'
group by A.codactor
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you actors WHO HAVE DONE MORE movies than  'Vincent Cassel'

```
SELECT A.name ,A.surname,count(*) HowManyMovies
FROM Plays P
INNER JOIN Actor A
ON P.codactor = A.codactor
GROUP BY A.name ,A.surname
HAVING count(*) > (
    SELECT COUNT(P.codfilm) HowManyMovies
    FROM Plays P
    INNER JOIN Actor A
        ON P.codactor = A.codactor
    WHERE A.name = 'Vincent Cassel'
    GROUP BY A.codactor
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's count how many times each actor starred in movies.

Then let's select only these actors who have their play count higher than maximum number for Vincent Cassel (this is to properly handle cases when we have more than one Vincent Cassel in our database). Including `coalesce()` let's us take care of a case where no plays are found or an actor is not present in our table.

```
with act_plays as (
select a."codactor", a."name", a."surname", count(*) as playcount
from "ACTOR" a
inner join "Plays" p on
  a."codactor" = p."codactor"
group by a."codactor", a."name", a."surname"
)
select *
from act_plays
where playcount > coalesce(( 
  select max(playcount) -- if more than one Vincent Cassel let's take max val
  from act_plays
  where "name" =  'Vincent' and "surname" = 'Cassel'
  ), 0)
```

We can safely use `INNER JOIN` when combining actors and plays because we need actors who starred in more films than Vincent Cassel, thus if it's 0 for Vincent we discard those actors who haven't starred in any film anyways.